# Circuit analysis: Two nodes as one?

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits

Can I treat these two nodes in the center as if there were only one node connecting these four components?

[image]

Comment: Yes, you can.  They are only distinct if there is some component between them.

Comment: For further reading:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node_%28circuits%29  *"In electrical engineering, node refers to any point on a circuit where two or more circuit elements meet. For two nodes to be different, **their voltages must be different**. When looking at circuit schematics, ideal wires have a resistance of zero. Since it can be assumed that there is no change in the potential across any part of the wire, **all of the wire in between any components in a circuit is considered part of the same node**"*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thare is only one node connecting elements B, D, E, and G.

The dots on the diagram are just to indicate that the lines do in fact connect, so that all of the wires are part of the same node.

In this kind of schematic diagram wires are considered as ideal, and all points on the wire are considered to be at an equal potential.